# failure to detect NA

Tags: r, date, dplyr

While I am trying to find `NA` I have a problem as below.

```
dta = data.frame(group0 = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3),
  date0 = c(as.Date("2018-09-01",format="%Y-%m-%d"),
                              as.Date("2018-09-02",format="%Y-%m-%d"),
                              as.Date("2018-09-03",format="%Y-%m-%d"),
                              as.Date("2018-09-04",format="%Y-%m-%d"),
                              as.Date("2018-10-01",format="%Y-%m-%d"),
                              as.Date("2018-10-02",format="%Y-%m-%d"),
                              as.Date("2018-10-02",format="%Y-%m-%d"),
                              as.Date("2018-10-03",format="%Y-%m-%d")),
  type0 = c("A","A","B","A","B","B","B","B"))
```

I have data like this and try to have a min date for each group with this a condition as below.

```
    dta2 = dta %>% group_by(group0) %>% summarise(tmp_date0 = min(date0[type0 == "A"]))
```

Then, I have this

```
> dta2
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  group0 tmp_date0 
   <dbl> <date>    
1      1 2018-09-01
2      2 2018-09-04
3      3 NA
```

When I run this

```
> is.na(dta2$tmp_date0)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Why the third one is `FALSE`?

Comment: It is internally `Inf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a coercion from `Inf` because there are no values that matching the value of "A" in the logical expression returning `logical(0)`

```
min(logical(0))
#[1] Inf
```

because it is `Date` class, the coercion to `NA` is not a real `NA`

```
as.Date(Inf) 
# NA

dput(as.Date(Inf))
#structure(Inf, class = "Date")

as.Date(Inf) %>%
    is.na
#[1] FALSE
```

It gets coerced to NA, but it is not NA, if we check the `dput`

```
dput(dta2$tmp_date0)
#structure(c(17775, 17778, Inf), class = "Date")
```

A check with `is.finite` further proves it

```
is.finite(dta2$tmp_date0)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

In order to prevent the `min` acting on `logical(0)` an option is to use an `if/else` condition

```
dta3 <- dta %>% 
    group_by(group0) %>%
    summarise(tmp_date0 = if(any(type0 == 'A')) min(date0[type0 == 'A']) else NA)
```

Now, the `is.na` correctly picks up

```
is.na(dta3$tmp_date0)
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```